# How to change the java DNS service provider

Tags: java, dns, service-provider, dnsjava

I'm building a fast web crawler and I need to have multithreaded DNS resolution, so I picked up a multithreaded DNS service provider called [dnsjava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/). Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to replace the default DNS Service Provider.

I went over the [README](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/dnsjava-current/README) file for dnsjava, but the instructions are not very through.

> Replacing the standard Java DNS
>   functionality:
>
> Beginning with Java 1.4, service
>   providers can be loaded at runtime. 
>   To load the dnsjava service provider,
>   build it as explained above and set
>   the system property:
>
> sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=dns,dnsjava
>
> This instructs the JVM to use the
>   dnsjava service provide for DNS at the
>   highest priority.

There are a couple of things that I'm unclear on:

1. Where do I place the dnsjava.jar?
2. Where is the system property supposed to be set (is it programmatic or some type of file change)?

I'm running on a Windows 7 machine and I'm not sure what I need to do to find/modify the system properties... help!?

**Update:**
Got it: `System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1","dns,dnsjava");`

Comment: Are you sure `System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1","dns,dnsjava");` works to be using DNSJava first, and only then falling back to the system DNS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wild guess.

1. Put the dnsjava.jar file in the classpath of your application.
2. Have the system property set before launching the main method in your application.

Comment: do I set the system property programatically? I created a Properties instance and I tried to find if it contains the key "sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider", but it didn't have it... am I on the right track?

Comment: It is most likely not defined yet, so it falls back to the default values.  I would suggest you ask Google about "sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1" and see what the results say.

Comment: Found it... `System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1")`, THANKS!

Comment: would you happen to know if there is a way to verify if the dnsjava Service Provider is actually being used?

Comment: Sorry no.  I would suggest having a closer look at the documentation to see what they recommend you use for debugging.

Comment: You can start the application in debug mode and connect to it with your IDE of choice. Set the breakpoint on `DNSJavaNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(String host)` When you perform your lookup, you should be able to see it enter this method.