# dnsjava can't resolve "localhost" on Linux machine

Tags: java, linux, hosts, dnsjava

After I registered [dnsjava as default Java DNS provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668058/how-to-change-the-java-dns-service-provider) I get a problem. It can't resolve local addresses which described in /etc/hosts file on my Linux machine. This file look something like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   servername
```

So if I try to resolve one of such names UnknownHostException happens:

```
org.xbill.DNS.Address.getByName("localhost");
org.xbill.DNS.Address.getByName("servername");
```

It's not a problem when you're using dnsjava along with default dns provider. Being a sole provider, dnsjava causes lots of errors in default libraries, which turn out to be highly dependent on localhost resolution capability. So, the question is: how to change behavior of dnsjava to resolve local hostnames?

**Edit.** Next code works fine:

```
java.net.InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
```

But *java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost()* method throws:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: servername
```

Answer (score 1):

`dnsjava` is a DNS client library; it talks to DNS servers. `/etc/hosts` is not part of the DNS protocol nor does `dnsjava` know anything about it.

See  this old post on a the dnsjava users mailing list from the guy who wrote it: http://old.nabble.com/DNS-Resolve-from-hosts-file-first-then-DNS-Server-td15431381.html

Nothing has changed in that regard.

If `java.net.InetAddress.getByName()` is working, then your DNS server is configured to respond to queries for `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks for the link! All of it sound normally. But method `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost()` attempts to return `servername` as local host name in my case. Because of DNS server doesn't know about such hostname I get UHE. Problem is that too many libraries want to know local host name. I can't change behavior of libraries and DNS server so I should change it in dnsjava.

Comment: NOTE: The URL in this answer no longer works (thanks Nabble), but it's available on the Wayback machine at https://web.archive.org/web/20111220074414/http://old.nabble.com/DNS-Resolve-from-hosts-file-first-then-DNS-Server-td15431381.html